# c# defer the save implementation

Tags: c#

I need assists ;-) to be honest not sure what to call it so if people come up with the more correct wording I will change the title to suit.

I have written a class for 'what ever' the class is like a utility class.. can be used in many projects across the entire app.

In the utility class.. there is a reference to the EF DB Context. This is for when i want to persist the results into the database.

I would like to remove the dependency on this being in the Utility class and rather pass in the save method.

I am struggling to figure out how you would do this. i.e. with c# Action i know you can pass in a method to be preformed i.e a pointer to a function. But how do I let that pointer know about things inside my Utility case.

I hope i worded all that correctly, please assist with either an example or link to what i am on about.

Showing code: not sure its necessary in this case. But here is a crude example.

```
public class UtilityCase
{
    public List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();

    public void AddPerson(string name)
    {

        Person newPerson = new Person {Name = name};
        Persons.Add(newPerson);

        if (Persons.Count > 10)
        {
            PersistClear();
        }

    }

    public void PersistClear()
    {
        //I want to be able to Set this from outside of the UtilityCase
        var context = new Context();

        //I want to remove the referance to the Entity (DB) Person
        foreach (Person item in Persons)
        {
            //add person to db 
        }
        context.saveChanges();

        Persons.Clear();
    }

}
```

DB entity case

```
public class Person
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So I understand that i would need to create a local class to the Utility to remove the reference to the Person (DB) but how do i get my function to inject to know about things inside the UtilityCase. Thanks

Comment: I've trouble understanding what you actually want to achieve. It sounds to me that you want to have a PersistClear() method, that does not have a dependency on Person and Context, which begs the question: Why have the method in the first place? Can you elaborate what it is you actually want?

Comment: I want to inject the save implementation... basically DDD and remove classes from the UtilityCase which make it have a dependency on other projects... i.e. in this case it is dependent on my Data layer.

Comment: And what would the responsibility of "PersistClear()" be? Just calling the delegate you passed in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like that?

```
//doesn't depends on specific Entity Data Model
public class UtilityCase
{
    public List<EntityObject> Persons = new List<EntityObject>();

    private readonly Action<IEnumerable<EntityObject>> _saveImpl;

    public UtilityCase(Action<IEnumerable<EntityObject>> saveImpl)
    {
        _saveImpl = saveImpl;
    }
    ...

    public void PersistClear()
    {
        _saveImpl(Persons);
    }
}
```

Call it from another project with specific Entity Data model (Context):

```
UtilityCase uc=new UtilityCase((col) =>
{
    //I want to be able to Set this from outside of the UtilityCase
    var context = new Context();

    //I want to remove the referance to the Entity (DB) Person
    foreach (EntityObject item in col)
    {
        //add person to db
        context.Persons.Add((Person)item));
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
});
```

PS: not run, may contain minor errors

Comment: ooo I'll look at this a little later... but at quick glance... you sir are the man.(provided my double check later ;-)) thanks let you know.

Comment: 100% what i was looking for! thank you. Obviously modified for my needs.. but gave me what i was looking for. Thanks so much for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you are asking but why do you need all this code and why can't you add the `Person` entity to the collection in `Context` like

```
var context = new Context();
context.Persons.Add(new Person {Name = name});
context.SaveChanges();
```

Not sure why you are maintaining an extra `List<Persons>` in your code. whatever, code you have shown can actually be done directly using the `Persons` collection present in your EF Context

Comment: @Seabizkit, your this statement making me confuse. Can you show a pseudo code showing what you are trying to do.